# Flutter rebuilding causing change in data

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm a beginner at Flutter and Dart and am trying to build a to-do list app that uses the SQFLite plugin to persist data. I have a list of tasks (objects of a custom class) and am trying to give users the option (via a dropdown menu) to select a particular category of tasks - the category id is stored as an attribute of the task. When I generate a filtered list based on tasks and use setState to set my class taskList to be this generated list, it simply rebuilds to the entire class list. I cannot figure out where this rebuilding is taking place.

My filterTasks function that takes in a category name, identifies its category id - the category name is '' in case the user is clearing the filter - and then loops through all tasks to find where the id matches (I realise I could do this with the database as well and select all where the id matches but even this means should work) and if there are matches, then it sets the tasks displayed to be this filtered list.

```dart
void filterTasks(String category) async {
    await updateList(); //gets the entire list
    print('Mid ${this.taskList}');
    if (category != '') {
      int filteredId = await getCategoryId(category);
      List<Task> filtered = [];
      int count = taskCount;
      for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        if (this.taskList[i].taskCategory == filteredId) {
          filtered.add(this.taskList[i]);
        }
      }
      if (filtered.isEmpty) {
        showSnackBar(context, "Error, no tasks of this category exist.", false);
        setState(() {
          categoryChoice = null;
        });
      } else {
        setState(() {
          this.taskList = filtered;
          this.taskCount = this.taskList.length;
          print('End ${this.taskList}');
        });
      }
    }
  }
```

The update list function simply retrieves the entire list of tasks and categories from the DB since a user may want to change between filters directly and not have to clean the filter. I set it to await since it is an async function and I thought that it may override the filtered list after completion of this filterTasks function.

This is the initial portion of my build function, where I call upon update list in case the taskList or categoryList is null, which isn't the case here.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print('Start ${this.taskList}');
    if (taskList == null || categoryList == null) {
      taskList = List<Task>();
      categoryList = List<Category>();
      updateList();
    }
    return Scaffold()//my widget tree
```

The code for the dropdown button that calls the function:

```dart
DropdownButton(
            hint: Text(
              'Filter',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: textColor,
              ),
            ),
            dropdownColor: bgColorPrimary,
            value: categoryChoice,//class variable
            items: this.categoryList?.map((Category instance) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(
                      value: instance.categoryName,
                      child: Text(
                        instance.categoryName,
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: categoryColorsMap[instance.categoryColour],
                            fontSize: 16.0),
                      ));
                })?.toList() ??
                [],
            onChanged: (newValue) {
              filterTasks(newValue);
            },
            icon: Icon(
              Icons.filter_list,
              color: textColor,
            ),
          )
```

The filter list is reset by another icon that is right after the dropdown button which simply sets categoryChoice to null (to show the dropdown hint) and calls the filterTasks with the parameter of ''.

EDIT:
After tinkering with some print statements, 4 in particular, with 3 shown in the code snippets and one at the start of the updateList function, I am now more intrigued. The print statement in the updateList simply says 'triggered' and the output is as follows:

```
//APP BOOT UP
I/flutter (18734): Start null
I/flutter (18734): triggered
I/flutter (18734): Start [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']
//THIS IS WHEN I FILTERED THE TASKS
I/flutter (18734): triggered
I/flutter (18734): mid [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']
I/flutter (18734): End [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']
I/flutter (18734): Start [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']
I/flutter (18734): Start [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']
```

And so while the taskList is getting updated, it isn't the updateList that makes it revert back to the whole list. I simply cannot figure out what does. Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

P.S I am a beginner at dart so I'm not entirely familiar with naming conventions and the finer OOP nuances, if you have any feedback about that, let me know as well :) Thank you for your help.

Comment: I suspect that It rebuilds the entire widget tree because your whole build method starts with a conditional that is changed in setState(). Basically taskList is your entry point and from that line, everything below is rebuilt.

Comment: Once the filterTasks method is run and the taskList is updated, the conditional will not pass right (since categoryList isn't null).

Comment: Hi, where do you store your category variable (the one you pass to the function filterTasks) ?

Comment: So this is a class variable that is changed by the dropdown button! I've used print statements as pseudo-debugging and the category passed to the function is the correct one! I'll add a snippet to show you with the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally fixed the error, and am leaving this here in case anyone makes beginner mistakes like me. The issue lay in the updateList as I suspected but later ruled out (much to my own stupidity) and since the function was composed of then statements, awaiting the function didn't do anything and once a filteredList was generated, it was quickly replaced the entire list as derived by the updateList. Changing the updateList function to async and using the await keyword meant that the filteredList would only generate after the list was updated.

OLD FUNCION:

```dart
void updateList() {
    Future<Database> dbFuture = databaseHelper.initialiseDatabase();
    dbFuture.then((database) {
      Future<List<Task>> taskListFuture = databaseHelper.getTaskList();
      taskListFuture.then((taskList) {
        setState(() {
          this.taskList = taskList;
          this.taskCount = taskList.length;
        });
      });

      Future<List<Category>> categoryListFuture =
          databaseHelper.getCategoryList();
      categoryListFuture.then((categoryList) {
        setState(() {
          this.categoryList = categoryList;
          this.categoryCount = categoryList.length;
        });
      });
}
```

NEW FUNCTION:

```dart
 void updateList() async {
    Database db = await databaseHelper.initialiseDatabase();
    List<Task> taskTemp = await databaseHelper.getTaskList();
    List<Category> categoryTemp = await databaseHelper.getCategoryList();
    setState(() {
      this.taskList = taskTemp;
      this.taskCount = taskTemp.length;
      this.categoryList = categoryTemp;
      this.categoryCount = categoryTemp.length;
    });
  }
```

This fixed the filtering error, I hope it can help anyone else stuck in a similar situation. Thank you to everyone who tried helping me.